# Python https Proxy

Tags: python, nginx, https, proxy, raspberry-pi

I have an embedded device (photovoltaic converter) installed which provides a normal http web interface (info and settings). The converter has a user authehtification but only by http.
Due security considerations I don't want to publish the server directly to the internet.
In my network I have also a Raspberry PI installed. So my idea is to proxy the http access to the photovoltaic converter by the PI and publish the web interface via https to the internet. What would be the best approach (Python script, squid, nginx) for this? Are there any examples availiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi is a computer. You can run a web server to proxy things just like you would on any normal setup, and https should work as well.

I would use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) as it's lightweight and easy to configure.

A simple configuration example:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

}
```

The server in port 80 will redirect all traffic to your https server. The https server will proxy all traffic to localhost:8080. Probably won't do as such, but you get the idea.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. I'm not sure about the authenitcation. The http page requires username and password. Will this by handled transparent by the proxy?

Comment: Works perfectly - with authentification.Thank You!